# Magento site won't fully render after server & domain move

Tags: php, magento

I recently moved a magento install to a new server and a new domain.  I updated all the entries in the database with the new domain and path.  The admin works fine, indexing works fine, cache management works fine.

However on the front end, the site renders all the way until the first product, and then it stops.  The rest of the products don't render, and neither does the footer or any other blocks.

I tried to switch back to the vanilla theme that magento ships with, and it still happens.

The files on the new server are exactly the same (rsynced), and the only difference in the db is the domain and path.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

If it helps, the currently broken url is http://stiles-store.ddmstaging.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a fatal error. Turn on developer mode and reload the page - you will see the error message.

You can turn on developer mode by two ways:
1. At backend
2. Change code in index.php from

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

to

```
//if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
//}
```

Comment: I did as you said and enabled developer mode.  Same behavior, and no errors are showing on the page.  No errors are showing the PHP error log either.  Is there some other setting that I need to enable?

Comment: In the end, it was a fatal error.  I was missing the GD plugin on my live server.

Answer (score 2):

This error is occurring because you might have specified some images or links of your development machine. So Magento is not able to connect to your local machine/development machine from where it is trying to fetch the components.

Try to check whether you have specified the links of your server on which you are currently running your magento instance .

Hope this helps you

Comment: This isn't the problem.  The page is actually not finishing rendering.  If the problem was what you're describing, the page would render fully but I wouldn't see any images or my links would point to the wrong spot.

Answer (score 1):

Missing GD support in PHP is the reason for this.

In our case GD support was compiled into PHP 5.3, but when we migrated to the new server with PHP 5.4 the sysadmin forgot to include the now shared GD module.

Unfortunately there were no error messages in the server and Magento logs. Basically this question resp. Jack's last comment saved me a ton of time!

Hope this will help others, as I was searching for the PHP version and product image URLs not rendering.

Comment: Yup. For centos run: 
`yum install gd gd-devel php-gd`
and
`service httpd restart`